# Rails 3: Loop shows more records than there should be

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, erb

Not exactly sure of what to call this issue. Still new to rails.

Situation: An *auction* contains many *lots*.
I'm showing an auction's lots in a url like */auctions/3/lots/*.

View:

```
<ul>
<% @lots.each do |lot| %>
  <li><%= lot.auction_id %>: <%= lot.id %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Outputs this:

```
<ul>
  <li>3: 1</li>
  <li>3: </li>
</ul>
```

I only have one *lot* in my database. Not sure where the extra loop instance is coming from.
This happens on any *lot* listing no matter which *auction* I'm looking at.

Also,
`<%= @lots.length %>` displays 2
`<%= @lots.size %>` displays 2
`<%= @lots.count %>` displays 1

My lots_controller looks like this:

```
def index
  @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
  @lots = @auction.lots
end

def create
  @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
  @lot = @auction.lots.build(params[:lot])

  if @lot.save
    redirect_to auction_lots_path, :notice => 'Lot was successfully created.'
  else
    render :action => "index"
  end
end
```

My models:

```
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :lots
end

class Lot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :auction
  ...
end
```

The `...`s are just `attr_accesssible` and `validates` lines.

The log when I hit the page was requested, here it is.

```
Started GET "/auctions/8/lots" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-13 16:35:51 -0500
Processing by LotsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"auction_id"=>"8"}
  Auction Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "auctions".* FROM "auctions" WHERE "auctions"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "8"]]
  Lot Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "lots".* FROM "lots" WHERE "lots"."auction_id" = 8
[#<Lot id: 18, description: "1923 Morgan", lot_number: 1, auction_id: 8, created_at: "2013-02-13 17:20:04", updated_at: "2013-02-13 17:20:04">]
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Lot Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "lots" WHERE "lots"."auction_id" = 8 LIMIT 1
  Rendered lots/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 17.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

**Update:**
Someone mentioned that it looks like I'm using `@auction.lots.build` somewhere.
And yes, I am. I have a form on the same page (index) where I can add lots.

```
<%= form_for(@auction.lots.build, :url => auction_lots_path(@auction)) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Changing `@auction.lots.build` got rid of the extra row, although now I can't create lots successfully. I'm not sure what to do. I probably have to set up something in the index method of the lots_controller, but I don't know what.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how are you setting `@lots`?

Comment: `@auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])   
@lots = @auction.lots`

Comment: It looks like the auction has a connection to a lot, that doesn't specify a lot ID. I would like to see the code that connects a lot to an auction.

Comment: I added my lots_controller code to my question.

Comment: Also adding your models code may be helpful. And what does Lot.find_by_auction_id(3) returns?

Comment: Change anton's to `Lot.find_all_by_auction_id(3)`

Comment: Oops, definitely `find_all_by_auction_id`.

Comment: I added my models code. Running `Lot.find_all_by_auction_id(3)` shows me only one lot.

Comment: When you're tailing the log (from command prompt in your app's root directory `tail -f log/development.log`)  And you hit the index action (`/auctions/3/lots`) What sql queries do you see the application running?  In your index method at the end add `Rails.logger.debug @lots.inspect` and give us that output from the log too.  I can't see anything obvious here...

Comment: I added the log to my question. I put the logger line at the end of my index method in lots_controller.rb and I don't see any output...

Comment: Sounds like you're calling auction.lots.build somewhere

Comment: Yeah, I am. In the create method of lots_controller. Is that wrong?

Comment: I've updated the question to show my index's form tag. I'm using @auction.lots.build which I now assume is incorrect.

Comment: I'm getting an extra data as nil also, did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This would happen in your create method if the lot failed to save. Because you used `@auction.lots.build`, that appends a lot record to the auction. If it doesn't save properly, it's still there unsaved. That explains why the "mystery" one doesn't have an id, and also why:

`<%= @lots.size %>` displays 2
`<%= @lots.count %>` displays 1

`@lots.count` is a database query, but `@lots.size` is just the size of the array in memory.

I would probably do something more like this in the create action:

```
def create
  @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
  @lot = @auction.lots.create!(params[:lot])
  redirect_to auction_lots_path, :notice => 'Lot was successfully created.'
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  render :action => "index"
end
```

... but of course others will prefer using if/else rather than rescuing the exception. There are other ways around this. You could do `@auction.reload.lots` to cull the unsaved one, but that's a little wierd. The normal rails thing to do in this case is re-render the form with the validation errors displayed and ask the user to fix them and try creating again.

Comment: This will only be the case if it was from a `POST` request.  If you just go to `/auction/3/lots` it won't hit the `create` action.  If he's getting this behavior from `index` then I think we need to see his model code defining the two models and their association.

Comment: Oh also, that `render action: 'index'` in his controller from the failed save *will not display any lots at all* because he only defined a `@lot` variable, `@lots` wouldn't exist. (It'll give him an error `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`)

Comment: both good points. I agree we'd need to see more code to see exactly what's going on. But I stand by the basic premise -- the extra element in the array must be an unsaved instance for some reason.

Comment: Yes...but it seems like it's coming from somewhere else, I don't see it in the supplied controller code.  It's either something in a before_filter in `application_controller` or something in the model (maybe the `Auction` model defines a `lots` method instead of using active_record's associations properly?)

Comment: Jeff said that there's an unsaved instance. Is there a way to just... remove it one-time?

Comment: nzifnab, I haven't added anything to my application_controller. (It just says `protect_from_forgery`). My Auction model code is in my question.

Comment: Actually, I reset the db, added a new lot to an auction and the extra row still appears consistently throughout all auctions. (But with the respective auction_id)

Answer (score -1):

This should help:

```
def create
  params[:lot].merge!({:auction_id =>  params[:auction_id]})
  @lot = Lot.new(params[:lot])

  if @lot.save
    redirect_to auction_lots_path, :notice => 'Lot was successfully created.'
  else
    render :action => "index"
  end
end
```

Comment: That doesn't actually help anything, that `render :action => "index"` is still going to give an `undefined method` error as I mentioned in Jeff Gran's answer.  And the OP's question appears to pertain to the `index` action, not the `create` action.